# Algorithm to loop through values in a HashMap and see how many times a specific HashSet occurs

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashset

I need to write a loop that will see if the values in a HashMap are equal and if they are see how many times they occur. Sets of numbers will be entered in through the Scanner (example input will be below) The following code will put the key of count and the value of the HashSet into the hashMap.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Type in your numbers followed by spaces and press enter");
    System.out.println("After every set entered type in any letter to enter more sets");
    System.out.println("Or enter * to finish");

    HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>> hset = new HashMap<>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = 1;

    HashSet<Integer> list = new HashSet<>();
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        while(sc.hasNextInt()) {
            list.add(sc.nextInt());
        }
        hset.put(count, new HashSet<>(list));
        count++;
        list.clear();
        sc.nextLine();
        if(sc.nextLine().equals("*")) {
            System.out.println("working");
            break;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
        //some code goes here
        //if(hset.get(x) == hset.get(j)) or something along these lines
   }
}

//Example Scanner input
1 2 3 4 5
10 9 8 7
5 4 3 2 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 2 3 5
1 2 3 6
6 4 2
2 4 6
4 2 6
4 6 2
6 2 4
1 3 2 4 5
15 14 13
5 3 2 1
79
7 9

//What the output should look like    
[7, 9]=1
[1]=1
[7, 8, 9, 10]=1
[13, 14, 15]=1
[1, 2, 3, 5]=2
[1, 2, 3, 6]=1
[2, 4, 6]=5
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]=3
[79]=1
```

Comment: SUGGESTION: 1) Copy the values from your HashMap into a sorted list 2) iterate through the sorted list to count "duplicates".  Q: It sounds like your Hashmap is just one big "set of numbers" - it doesn't matter which numbers are grouped by line, and which are between lines.  Correct?  Or is each line a different "set", and you want to compare the sets between lines?  Please clarify...

Comment: Duplicate of this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67205919/read-multiple-hashsets-from-scanner-on-different-lines-in-a-loop/67206225#67206225

Answer (score 1):

Abstracting from your specific instance, you have a list of items and you want to count how many times each item occurs in the list.

A classic way to achieve the result is to use a Map with items as keys and counters as values; then process the list item by item, check if the item is already in the Map, if not create entry and set counter to 1, otherwise increase the existing counter.

Coming back to your problem, your items are set of integers (one per line), so the map will be a `Map<Set<Integer>,Integer>` and **not** a `Map<Integer,Set<Integer>>` like in your code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Type in your numbers followed by spaces and press enter");
    System.out.println("After every set entered type in any letter to enter more sets");
    System.out.println("Or enter * to finish");

    //Map of items and counters 
    Map<Set<Integer>, Integer> hset = new HashMap<>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Read line by line with the scanner, then process each line, since when you call
    //nextInt() ad end of line the scanner will eat up EOL and silently proceed with
    //the next line
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line=sc.nextLine();
        if(line.equals("*")) {
            break;
        }
        //I kept the variable name, but please don't name 'list' a set!
        Set<Integer> list = new HashSet<>();
        for (String num: line.split(" ")) {
            num=num.trim();
            if (num.length()>0) {
                list.add(Integer.parseInt(num));
            }
        }

        //Just in case of blank lines
        if (list.isEmpty()) continue;

        //Check if the set is already in the map and get the counter
        Integer count=hset.get(list);
        if (count==null) {
            //Not found, new counter
            count=0;
        }
        //Increase the counter (both new and old ones)
        hset.put(list, count+1);
    }

    //Print
    hset.entrySet().forEach((e)-> System.out.println(e.getKey()+"="+e.getValue()));
}
```